# Error when using "moving" on a matrix input in DolphinDB

Tags: matrix, moving-average, dolphindb

I want to calculate the moving average for each column of a matrix in DolphinDB. But I encountered an error when using higher order function `moving(avg, m, w)`,  which is shown in the following figure.

[image]

However, the function `mavg(m, w)` works fine with the same input. Can someone shed light on the cause of the issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the `moving` function in DolphinDB only supports vectors, dictionaries and tables as the input.

For your question, try the following two methods:

- `mavg(m, w)`
- `each(moving{avg,,w}, m)`: the higher-order function `each` is used to
  apply `moving{avg,,w}` to each column of the matrix "m".